# Arabic support in React DatePicker library, with number also change in arabic

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker, arabic-support

This calendar is built on Angular with material Design, I need same the same output when I change my locale to ar-SA in react with react-datepicker

[image]

When I am changing locale to "ar-SA"(Arabic- Saudi Arabia), it is just placing the items from right to left but not changing the numbers and text in Arabic.

I have tried through this code.

```
<DatePicker
      locale="ar-SA"
      dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
      selected={new Date()}
      popperPlacement="top-end"
      onChange={(date) => alert(date)}
      />
```

I have also tried some alternative to translate the date through the following:

```
import { FormattedDate } from "react-intl"
```

but this is also not helpful.

I want full Arabic support on same calendar with the text and numbers in Arabic.

Comment: have you tried this?
import { registerLocale} from  "react-datepicker";
import sa from 'date-fns/locale/ar-SA';
registerLocale('sa', sa)

Comment: I have tried this, but numbers are not getting changed, other things are changed, but mainly I need the translation of numbers also.